# mysql connect issue on centos7 server through python

Tags: python, mysql, centos7

I install mysql on centos7 server(server ip is 192.168.1.83)。
Now I use python script to connect mysql，but the python script went wrong

Snapshots:

[image]
  [image]

The host set in python script is 192.168.1.83,but it turn to 192.168.1.70 when I run the script.192.168.1.70 is my computer local IP.I search though google,but can't find any solution.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow! Some users can't read images so please put type out any error messages. Also without including a MVCE (in particular the python script that connects to mysql), it will be difficult to help you. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that this user `root` which coming through this host `192.168.1.170` will not be able to connect to the database which you are trying to access at `192.168.1.83`.
What you need to do is to [allow remote MySQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/2336650) from the host `192.168.1.170` for this user `root` which will make the script able to work as expected.